# ListView refresh taking it to the top of the list

Tags: android, android-listview

Scenario: I am using a listview with custom Adapter. I am fetching data every 5 seconds and then displaying it in the listview.

Problem: After every refresh the list scrolls at the top. I would want the list to stay as is from the scroll standpoint and just the underlying data to be refreshed.

Current code: This is called every time I fetch a new data.

```
mListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, mListData);
mList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
```

Comment: Does it work if you instead of creating a new adapter replace your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter? Or if it isn't a subclass of ArrayAdapter, registering a DataSetObserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code please try to put every time you fetch data this one:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Question. Did calling notifyDataSetChanged() keep your ListView where you last left off?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling this, you should set the new data to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As you get new mListData then just invalidate the adapter not re-initialized the adapter you can call like this

```
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
mList.setSelection(mListData.size() - CONSTANT.CONTENT_SIZE);
```

This way the listview will not refresh to the top.
Or you can also use

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged
```

by updating the binded list.

Comment: what is this CONSTANT.CONTENT_SIZE ?

Comment: This setSelection will set the listview at the listitem you want to be on top. Let us say ur list has 10 items. And you update with 5 items. then This CONSTANT.CONTENT_SIZE = 5.

This CONSTANT.CONTENT_SIZE is the no of items you update with the list.

Comment: This is not related to question then, the issue is to make sure the list does not show on top again.

Answer (score 0):

This Worked For Me:

```
adapter.setData(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```