# How to keep ListView in the last position that is was before notifydatasetchanged is called

Tags: java, android-listview

this question has been asked in 2011 but i cant find the answer so i get this question and re-post it.

> I have expanded list view, 30 items , when i reaches to the bottom i load 30 more. then i called notifyDataSetChanged , the problem is the list moves to the top, so lost my current selection. I wanted, list should add more but it should goes to bottom, my selection stat should not be changed, like other apps. They added new items at bottom silently. How to achieve this?

Comment: I honestly haven't had that problem. But to be fair I have been using a CursorLoader. There is a possibility that if you are using a CursorAdapter with your ListView that when it refreshes your ListView it is kept where you last left off. Of course this is just incase nobody else answers it. I did a quick search and I have not found anything quickly available. So thats just a last resort thing.

Comment: I am using my custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Well then please post your code so we can try and see what you are doing wrong. I've tested mine really quick and it definitely updates in the last position I left it. It seems the other person that also used `notifyDataSetChanged` also had the same results. I say its something in your code thats causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did a little bit more digging. I was right, it should honestly not be refreshing at the top again. This exact same question was answered, and it seemed to work:

[ListView refresh taking it to the top of the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563099/listview-refresh-taking-it-to-the-top-of-the-list)

It also works perfectly for me. But again, if it does not work then your other option is to use a CursorLoader (my situation), but I think the underlying code that we do not see also called `notifyDataSetChanged`, so I am not sure what else can be done. But it would be very helpful to see actual code as you have posted none, meaning there could be something that you are doing wrong.

Comment: the setSelection(position) method work very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hmm, I did not know that method accomplished what you wanted. Where does it place the selected item? At the top of the list? But either way, I am confused as to why it wasn't just automatically leaving where you last left off. Like the other person and I have experience, its just working. There must be something in your code. It'd be nice to see how you actually refresh you Adapter. Up to you though. As long as your problem was solved, its all good..